# Why JVM does't execute the code?

Tags: java, jvm

I'm testing branch prediction, the code like this:

```
//first loop
int sortedSum = 0;
long sortedStartTime = System.nanoTime();
for (int i = 0; i < sortedArray.length; i++) {
    if (sortedArray[i] < 0) {
        sortedSum += sortedArray[i];
    }
}
long sortedTime = System.nanoTime() - sortedStartTime;

//second loop
int randomSum = 0;
long randomStartTime = System.nanoTime();
for (int i = 0; i < randomArray.length; i++) {
    if (randomArray[i] < 0) {
        randomSum += randomArray[i];
    }
}
long randomTime = System.nanoTime() - randomStartTime;

System.out.println("random time: " + randomTime);
System.out.println("sorted time: " + sortedTime);
```

It's simple print the time about each for loop.

Note that the `sortedSum` and `randomSum` is assigned in the loop but never accessed.

We don't talk about the branch prediction here, but the output result.
The output is:

```
random time: 32
sorted time: 1595942
```

Then, I put the second for loop before the first(first randomArray loop, second sortedArray).
The output is:

```
random time: 1541919
sorted time: 40
```

It seems the JVM doesn't execute the second loop. I decompile the class file, the decompiler doesn't erase anything.

Why? And why JVM DO execute the first loop?

P.S.
environment is:

```
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
java version "1.7.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_11-b21)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.6-b04, mixed mode)
```

Comment: During your first loop, the JVM is just warming up. Make a third loop to warm up the JVM before you measure the other two.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java

Comment: The question topic is wrong as JVM is actually executing both loops. It is timings that are under question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you runtime code enough it triggers the whole method to be optimised (in the background)

This means if you have a loop which iterates over 10K times and it doesn't do anything, you are actually timing how long it takes to detect the loop doesn't do any thing and replace it.

In the case of the second loop, the method has already been optimise away, in either case.

I suggest you have an outer loop which runs this test 3 times and you should see what I mean.

The reason it can drop the loop is;

- and you don't use the value calculated, so the `calculateSum` can be dropped
- then the array access isn't needed
- then the loop itself isn't need.

Comment: Yes, running the test several times (like puting the code inside function to cal)

Comment: @PaulVerest Running the test from the start several times, is not like running it several times in a loop.  For performance it can be very different.

Answer (score 0):

I **suppose** this:

We are talking about Just-In-Time Compilation here. The compiler optimizes only some time after he started executing. I would guess that he optimizes everything away. The first loop is executed as long as the JIT compiler didn't kick in yet.

Comment: Why do you tthink that Just-In-Time Compilation is in independent thread?

Comment: What makes you think that i think it is in an independent thread?

Answer (score 0):

I think it has nothing to do with Java, but CPU, memory and caches:

At first `System.nanoTime()` app is in memory, the executing code in CPU cache level 1 (at the speed of CPU). When program starts to execute, CPU will start putting memory blocks ahead
in level 1 or 2 cashes, so sequential read/write will see increase in speed.

Try using arrays of size much larger then CPU level 3 cache, e.g. 10MB and randomized indexes, that is prepare array of indexes in random order. That will eliminate CPU cashing effects.